# PHP CURLOPT PUT method

Tags: php, curl, post, put

I am trying to do a PUT call on php using curlopt but the DELETE and POST methods work fine, and the PUT method no, I have an 400 error.
I am using the following code:

```
$url = 'https://theURL';
echo " \n URL:\n".$url." "; //The URL is correct
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");

$headers[] = 'Content-length: 0'; //I don't have a body so the header is 0
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($ch);
```

If i Don't put the header part, i have this error:

> HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.

But I don't have a body so I just put the content-length as 0. I have also tried to put a number there  but I have a different error.

The error I am getting is this:

> REQUEST ERROR: The server encountered an error processing the request.

Comment: I'm guessing you are trying to consume an API? You should read their documentation to find out what can cause a 400 response. Not much we can do without more information

Comment: Usually a PUT is used to send data, by convention. So it would be surprising if the API expects such a request without a body. What exactly are you trying to do with this request? Is there any API documentation?

Comment: could you just try from terminal smth like: curl -X PUT YOUR_URL and check what's up